# How to set dispaly: none; of button in script tag?

Tags: javascript, button

How to set dispaly: none; of button in script tag ?

to disable button i use this

```
    if(.....................)
    {
        $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
```

but if i want to display: none; button how can i do ?

i try to use

```
if(.....................)
{
    $(".load_more").hide();
}
```

but not work ?

Comment: show some html please

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Faron: Today `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: `$(".load_more").hide();` should work show the HTML

Comment: EDITED: maybe consider revising to this: `.prop('disabled', true)`? (thanks @elclanrs)

Comment: Please be clear if you want to hide it (display:none) or disable the button.

Comment: display: none; thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<button>Button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('button').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Code at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7L68c/

Comment: my html is `<button class="load_more" id="load_more_button">load More</button>` , i must to use class="load_more", do you have other way , thank you.

Comment: You can do: 
document.getElementById('load_more_button').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
or just
document.getElementById('load_more_button').hide() if you have jquery.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if(.....................)
{
    $("#buttonID").css("display", "none");
}
```